# set wordpress post's permalink for specific page

Tags: wordpress

When I add/edit post I can change slug of the permalink. But I can't add slashes.
So assume I have

```
http://domain.com/myslug
```

but I need

http://domain.com/myslug1/myslug2

when I save it does

```
http://domain.com/myslug1myslug2
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a page, let's say `domain.com/careers`, WordPress has to figure out which post to retrieve from the database.

It will look at all of its rewrite rules and try to find one that matches the request. In this case, the last rule will catch it:

```
[(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

It will pass in `careers` (`$matches[1]`) as the `pagename` value, dissect it accordingly, and then look in the database for a post called `careers`.

When you visit a page called `domain.com/careers/internships`, the last rule will apply again. This time it will pass in `careers/internships`, dissect it accordingly, set the parent of the post to `careers`, and then look in the database for a post called `internships` that matches the parent.

If WordPress were to let you set the slug to `myslug1/myslug2`, a couple assumptions WordPress makes would be wrong.

1. There is no parent page called `myslug1`
2. There is no page called `myslug2`
3. There is no rewrite rule that lets WordPress know how to handle a `myslug1/myslug2` slug

All that said, it may still be possible to accomplish what you want, but maybe not in the way of making up slugs will-nilly. There has to be a pattern, some kind of rule, that you can give WordPress that says "if x, then y".

For example, you could have a meta box with an input field that whenever you entered something in it, that slug would appear at the end of the URL. Or perhaps you can sandwich a custom slug between `domain.com` and `myslug2`.

Here are a few things to look into:

1. [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function - Allows you to specify additional rewrite rules
2. [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) function - Make WordPress aware of custom query string variables
3. [query_vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) filter - Allows query vars to be manipulated prior to executing the query
4. [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action - Executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load

Another approach might be to create a parent page with `myslug1` and then a child page with `myslug2`. Or, depending on your needs, you may also take a look at [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). You can have a custom post type called `myslug1` and then posts with in it, where one post would be `myslug2`.

If you have specific questions about implementing one of the aforementioned, look through Stack Overflow or post another question with details if you can't find the answer.

Comment: there really is url myslug1/myslug2 so I can open it manually but I want to set permalink which refer to myslug1/myslug2, see?

Comment: ex, type link in the url bar of the browser and press go or enter :)

Comment: Just because you type it in, doesn't mean it exists. Take a look at my answer on options to actually make WordPress acknowledge your URL.